# numpy group rows from large array

Tags: python, numpy

group the rows having same first element and find max according to last column.

Like row 0 and 1 have same starting element so go to last column and find max from it
and return that row without looping .

```
utl = np.array ([[ 21. ,            0.01      ],
                 [ 21. ,            0.02      ],
                 [ 26. ,            0.04      ],
                 [ 26. ,            0.03      ],
                 [ 26. ,            0.03      ],
                 [ 34. ,            0.03      ],
                 [ 34. ,            0.09      ],
                 [ 26. ,            0.03      ]])
```

output must be

```
[ 21. ,            0.02      ]
[ 34. ,            0.09      ]
[ 26. ,            0.04      ]
```

Comment: Is the final order important?

Comment: no, final order not important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `np.lexsort`, you can get the maximum by index:

```
sort_idx = np.lexsort(utl.T[::-1])
```

The differences in the sorted first column are going to tell you which index to grab from the second:

```
max_idx = np.r_[np.flatnonzero(np.diff(utl[idx, 0])), len(idx) - 1]
min_idx = np.r_[0, np.flatnonzero(np.diff(utl[idx, 0])) + 1]
```

The results can be extracted immediately:

```
minima = utl[idx[min_idx], 1]
maxima = utl[idx[max_idx], 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

If the final order of the rows is not important:

```
# sort by first and second column
a = utl[np.lexsort((utl[:,1], utl[:,0]))]

# get positions of group change
# as we want the max, we take the last row per group
_, idx = np.unique(a[:,0], return_index=True)
idx2 = (idx-1)%a.shape[0]  # or idx2 = np.r_[idx[1:]-1, [a.shape[0]-1]]

# split
a[idx2]
```

output:

```
array([[21, 0.02],
       [26, 0.04],
       [34, 0.09]])
```

###### solution for the min

```
a = utl[np.lexsort((utl[:,1], utl[:,0]))]
_, idx = np.unique(a[:,0], return_index=True)
a[idx]
```

Comment: That's not what `sort(axis=0)` does...

Comment: Which is why your answer doesn't match. You likely want `lexsort`. No need for `unique` at all.

Comment: @MadPhysicist thanks, oversight from my side, I fixed it. If you have a better solution, you can provide it ;)

Comment: `unique` performs a second sort. I posted a `lexsort` solution that only does one sort followed by diff and indexing

Comment: @MadPhysicist thanks for the details and solution, from a practical perspective, however, it doesn't seem to have a very different timing. Maybe once the array is sorted an additional "sorting" is not really causing much loss